# Gradle complains "No such file or directory"

Tags: groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio & Gradle build script.

Under the root of my Android project, there is a folder named 'other', inside 'other' folder, there is a properties file *my.properties*.

```
-MyApp/
     …
    -other/
         -my.properties  
    -build.gradle
```

In my **build.gradle**, I try to access my.properties :

```
task accessMyProperties {
    def folderName = 'other';

    //Gradle complains this line
    def file = new File("$folderName/my.properties");
    ...
}
```

But gradle complains that:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyApp'.
> other/my.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Why gradle arises the above error? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Be careful about using pure relative paths in Gradle build scripts; those rely on the working directory at the time the build is invoked, which isn't something you should depend on. It's much better to ground your paths against `$projectDir` or `$rootDir`. Try something like this:

```
def file = new File("$projectDir/$folderName/my.properties");
```

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html for a list of variables you can use.